# jQuery slider - set every slider to have max = value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I have a webpage whereby when I create the jQuery sliders, the max is set to 100

Each slider is then set to have a value and when the page first loads, each slider has max to be the value of value

```
function initSliders() {
    $(".slider").slider({
      range: "min",
      min: 0,
      max:100,
      create: function(event, ui) {
        var classname = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).slider("value", $(',' + className).val());
        $(this).slider("option", "max", $(',' + className).val());
      }
   })
}
```

This works fine as when the page is loaded, each slider is looped through

If I amend one slider, the function is called again and only the changed slider is processed. All the others return to a max of 100

How can I set all sliders to have the max option the same as the value

So instead of `max:100` when creating, `max:value`

Comment: Your `$(',' + classname)` should be `$('.' + classname)`  (ie dot, not comma) - is that a typo in the question, or is it like that in your code?

Comment: You should separate your init function from you update function - ie don't call `initSliders()` when the value changes, but call a different function that sets just the relevant options, eg `$(".slider").slider("option", "value", value).slider("option", "max", value);`

Comment: The 'create' method will only get called when the slider is first created, it shouldn't get called on subsequent calls (though maybe it does? either way another reason to keep create/update separate).